# Big Endian vs. Little Endian in Qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit, q#

I've noticed that Q# favors Little Endian. Meaning that most operations are designed for this type of encoding. 
Is is it the same with Qiskit?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Qiskit uses little-endian for both classical bit ordering and qubit ordering.

*For classical bits:*

A 3-bit classical register `creg` with value `abc` has `creg[0]=c`, `creg[1]=b`, `creg[2]=a`.

*For qubits:*

The ordering is with respect to the tensor-product structure of the state space. So a 3-qubit quantum register `qreg` with wave-function $|\psi\rangle = |A\otimes B\otimes C\rangle = |ABC\rangle$ has `qreg[0]`$= |C\rangle$, `qreg[1]`$= |B\rangle$, `qreg[2]`$= |A\rangle$.

Similarly for representing unitary matrices of a circuit. $U = U_A \otimes U_B \otimes U_C = U_A U_B U_C$ would have $U_C$ acting on `qreg[0]`, $U_B$ acting on `qreg[1]` and $U_A$ acting on `qreg[2]`.

Comment: https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits/3_summary_of_quantum_operations.html#Basis-vector-ordering-in-Qiskit

Answer (score 2):

> Note that the bits are labelled from right to left. So cr[0] is the one to the furthest right, and so on. As an example of this, here's an 8 qubit circuit with a Pauli X
> on only the qubit numbered 7, which has its output stored to the bit numbered 7.

https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-appendix/qiskit.html

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, to put it for an example circuit:

[image]

Comment: The example here is in fact the exact opposite definition. See @cjwood's answer above. In this 6 qubit example, the bit string would read 0 except for the 6th qubit which has the X gate: q_5 = 1. The ordering in the quantum state in little endian is $| q_5, q_4, q_3, q_2, q_1, q_0 \rangle$, so the bit string is $|100000\rangle$