# Is IBM Q composer using little-endian representation for multi-qubit states?

Tags: quantum-state, ibm-q-experience

I am still confused when I am trying to use the [IBM Q composer](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/composer) to reproduce some quantum circuits I found in different papers, and I am wondering if it is because there are **two ways** to represent a multi-qubit state in a quantum circuit.

The multi-qubit state $|xy\rangle$ can be represented in a quantum circuit by

1. putting the $|x\rangle$ qubit (left)  on top, and the $|y\rangle$ one below, or by
2. putting the $|y\rangle$ qubit (right) on top, and the $|x\rangle$ one below.

*Is that correct?*

1. The convention of putting on top of the circuit the qubit that is the furthest to the **left** on the state, is called **big-endian**, while
2. The convention of putting on top of the circuit the qubit that is the furthest to the **right** on the state, is called **little-endian**.

*Is that correct?*

[IBM Q composer](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/composer) is putting the on top of the circuit the qubit that is the furthest to the **right** on the state, meaning it is using the **little-endian** representation of multi-qubit states.

*Is that correct?*

Comment: **Related**: [Big Endian vs. Little Endian in Qiskit](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8244)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM Q Experience and Qiskit both use the [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Little-endian) format.

> The multi-qubit state $|xy\rangle$ can be represented in a quantum
>   circuit by
>
> 1. putting the $|x\rangle$ qubit (left)  on top, and the $|y\rangle$ one below, or by
> 2. putting the $|y\rangle$ qubit (right) on top, and the $|x\rangle$ one below.
>
> *Is that correct?*

Yes. The IBM Q Composer uses convention 1.

> 1. The convention of putting on top of the circuit the qubit that is the furthest to the **left** on the state, is called **big-endian**,
>      while
> 2. The convention of putting on top of the circuit the qubit that is the furthest to the **right** on the state, is called
>      **little-endian**.
>
> *Is that correct?*

Yes. The point being that the qubits are numbered starting from the top (i.e., `q[0]`, `q[1]`, `q[2]`,...).

> [IBM Q composer](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/composer) is putting the on top of the circuit the qubit
>   that is the furthest to the **right** on the state, meaning it is
>   using the **little-endian** representation of multi-qubit states.
>
> *Is that correct?*

Correct.

Comment: Many thanks @Sanchayan for answering directly (and clearly) my questions, in addition of pointing to a related question/answer. I had seen it, but as a newcomer I was (am still) not 100% sure about the relationship between IBM Q Composer and Qiskit. As a newcomer, I can also tell that this is quite confusing when trying to compare two circuits that are using different convention! Do you know about any initiatives trying to standardize that, or at least proposing a way to clearly indicate which convention is used.