# Hadamard on first qubit for two qubit state doesn't output what it should on Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I'm using python `qiskit==0.36.2`.
The following code:

```
sv = Statevector.from_label('00')
mycircuit = QuantumCircuit(2)
mycircuit.h(0)
sv = sv.evolve(Operator(mycircuit))
print(sv.data)
```

Yeilds:
`[0.70710678+0.j 0.70710678+0.j 0.        +0.j 0.        +0.j]`
Which doesn't make sense, because Hadamard on the first qubit (qubit 0) should be equal to $1/\sqrt(2)(|00\rangle+|10\rangle)$ yet the output I get corresponds to $1/\sqrt(2)(|00\rangle+|01\rangle)$.

I'm confused as to why this happens.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Qiskit uses little-endian<sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)</sup> for bit ordering. So, $|01\rangle$ means that first qubit in the state $|1\rangle$ and second qubit in the state $|0\rangle$.

For more details see the answers [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/9880/9474), [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/18633/9474), and [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/8370/9474).