# CCX (Toffoli) gate calculation

Tags: qiskit

I expected |110> since we do

```
a -> a 
b -> b
c -> ab + c (mod 2)
```

since x 0 -> 1 and 1+1 = 0 mod 2
we get 110. Why is qiskit returning 011?

[image]

Comment: This is because Qiskit uses [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) for bit ordering. See [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/26797/9474).

Answer (score 0):

This is just because of the qubit ordering. The 0 in the result $|011\rangle$ is the most significant qubit and corresponds to q_2 in the circuit diagram.