# Confused about the application of Hadamard gate to uncorrelated qubits

Tags: qiskit, hadamard

Why does applying the following circuit on a $00$ state produce
$|0\rangle \otimes  |+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |01\rangle)$. Shouldn't it produce $ |+\rangle \otimes  |0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |10\rangle)$?

[image]

Comment: See also here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8244/big-endian-vs-little-endian-in-qiskit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qubit ordering in Qiskit: qubit 0 is the rightmost one, i.e., the least significant bit.