# Coping values based on indicator qubit in Qiskit

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, qiskit

Give the following input:
$$
A: 1110 \\
B: 0111 \\
\text{indicator}: 0 \text{ or } 1
$$
How do I copy the value of A or B to target qubits if indicator is 0 or 1 respectively?

In the image below, the `indicator=0` so the value of the `copy_of_a_or_b` qubits should resemble `a_input` qubits:

[image]

How can I do this in Qiskit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are looking for a classical operation called *multiplexer*. It is possible to build such operation with Qiskit's uniformly controlled gates (`UCGate`). More info in [here](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.uc).

However, this way might not be the easier way. After reading Cryoris' answer, here is my version of your example (which piggyback on [Cryoris' great answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/14950/1859)):

Let's set your current circuit:

```
from qiskit import *

a_input = QuantumRegister(4, name='a')
b_input = QuantumRegister(4, name='b')

inputs = QuantumCircuit(a_input, b_input)

inputs.initialize('1110', a_input)
inputs.initialize('0111', b_input)

inputs.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

(side note, if your run `inputs.decompose().draw('mpl')` you will notice that the order of the $X$ gates are going to be "in reverse". That's because [Qiskit endianness](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8244/big-endian-vs-little-endian-in-qiskit).)

Now, time to create the multiplexer. This scales up the [Cryoris' answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/14950/1859):

```
from qiskit.circuit.library import CXGate

indicator = QuantumRegister(1, name='indicator')
a_or_b = QuantumRegister(4, name='aORb')

multiplexer = QuantumCircuit(a_input, b_input, indicator, a_or_b)
for i in range(4):
    # If indicator is 0, copy from A
    multiplexer.append(CXGate().control(1, ctrl_state='0'), [indicator, a_input[i], a_or_b[i]])
    
multiplexer.barrier(a_input, b_input)

for i in range(4):
    # If indicator is 1, copy from B
    multiplexer.append(CXGate().control(1, ctrl_state='1'), [indicator, b_input[i], a_or_b[i]])

multiplexer.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

The register `a_or_b` needs to be measured:

```
output = ClassicalRegister(4, name='output')
measure = QuantumCircuit(a_or_b)
measure.measure_all(a_or_b)
```

The composed result:

```
circuit = inputs + multiplexer + measure
circuit.draw('mpl')
```

[image]

Finally, we need to "set" the `indicator` qubit. Once circuit for each possibility:

```
indicator0 = QuantumCircuit(indicator)
indicator0.initialize('0', indicator)

indicator1 = QuantumCircuit(indicator)
indicator1.initialize('1', indicator)
```

Time to test how it works:

```
job = execute(indicator0 + circuit, backend=BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'))
job.result().get_counts().keys()
```

```
dict_keys(['1110'])
```

```
job = execute(indicator1 + circuit, backend=BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'))
job.result().get_counts().keys()
```

```
dict_keys(['0111'])
```

Comment: Thanks. the structure and approach you took to answer the question is very good. Very helpful for indiviaudal stepping into quantum programming such as myself. Much appreciated. Didn't realise how much I took for granted in classical programming until I started learning quantum computing

Answer (score 1):

"Copying" a bit value from one qubit to another in this sense means applying a $CX$ gate where the source qubit is the control. If you additionally want to control this operation on an indicator qubit you can add another control. Then you have a $CCX$ or Toffoli. If you use an "ordinary" or closed control, the bit value will be copied if the indicator is 1. If you sandwich the control with two $X$ gates however -- an open control -- it will copy when the indicator is 0.
In your case you could just apply two $CCX$ gates per bit where once you use an open control on the indicator and once a closed control on the indicator.

In circuits (for only one bit, for several qubits just repeat this operation):

```
>>> from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
>>> from qiskit.circuit.library import XGate
>>> qr_a, qr_b, qr_i, qr_t = QuantumRegister(1, 'a'), QuantumRegister(1, 'b'), QuantumRegister(1, 'indicator'), QuantumRegister(1, 'target')
>>> circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr_a, qr_b, qr_i, qr_t)
>>> open_ccx = XGate().control(2, ctrl_state='01')
>>> closed_ccx = XGate().control(2)  # per default ctrl_state='00'
>>> circuit.append(open_ccx, [qr_a, qr_i, qr_t])  # copy A if indicator is 0
>>> circuit.append(closed_ccx, [qr_b, qr_i, qr_t])  # copy B if indicator is 1
>>> circuit.draw()

        a_0: ──■───────
               │
        b_0: ──┼────■──
               │    │
indicator_0: ──o────■──
             ┌─┴─┐┌─┴─┐
   target_0: ┤ X ├┤ X ├
             └───┘└───┘
```

And now the nicer solution by using a blockwise control. Since Qiskit can control arbitrary operations we can just define our custom `copy` operation consisting of 4 $CX$ gates and then control this, once open and once closed. Like so:

```
>>> qr_a, qr_b, qr_i, qr_t = QuantumRegister(4, 'a'), QuantumRegister(4, 'b'), QuantumRegister(1, 'indicator'), QuantumRegister(4, 'target')
>>> circuit = QuantumCircuit(qr_a, qr_b, qr_i, qr_t)
>>> copy = QuantumCircuit(8)  # circuit to copy 4 bits
>>> copy.cx(range(4), range(4, 8))
>>> open_copy = copy.control(1, ctrl_state='0')
>>> closed_copy = copy.control(1, ctrl_state='1')
>>> circuit.append(open_copy, qr_i[:] + qr_a[:] + qr_t[:])
>>> circuit.append(closed_copy, qr_i[:] + qr_b[:] + qr_t[:])
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @Cryoris, will give it a try and report back. much appreciated