# ket statevector of a 2-quibit system

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises

Given the following code:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)

# This calculates what the state vector of our qubits would be
# after passing through the circuit 'qc'
ket = Statevector(qc)

# The code below writes down the state vector.
# Since it's the last line in the cell, the cell will display it as output
ket.draw()
```

when executed, will output:

`Statevector([1.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j] \n            dims=(2, 2))`

which is expected result, as per my understanding, as $|00\rangle = [1 0 0 0 ]$

But when we apply $x$-gate on qubit 0 as in:

```
qc.x(0)

ket = Statevector(qc)
ket.draw()
```

the output is:

`Statevector([0.+0.j, 1.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 0.+0.j]\n            dims=(2, 2))`

which is not correct, as per my understanding, because applying the $x$-gate on first qubit will make the multi-qubit state $|10\rangle = [0 0 1 0]$, but the output of the above is $[0 1 0 0]$.

Please help me to understand this?

Also, here in the outputs `dims=(2, 2))`, shouldn't it be  `dims=(4, 1))`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that qiskit orders qubits oppositely from what you might have expected: it uses the "little endian" convention. This is explained in (slightly) greater detail in previous questions such as [this one](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8244/big-endian-vs-little-endian-in-qiskit).

The `dims` function on statevector is *not* giving you the dimensions of the vector. It is giving you a list of the dimensions of the individual quantum systems. Here you have two qubits (i.e. each of dimension 2).

Comment: what about dimensions? shouldn't it be (4,1) instead of (2,2) ?