# The Qiskit code's output doesn't seem to be what I expected

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, programming, quantum-state, quantum-algorithms

```
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer

qreg = QuantumRegister(2)
creg = ClassicalRegister(2)
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg,creg)

circuit.x(qreg[0]) #10
circuit.x(qreg[1]) #11
circuit.cx(qreg[0],qreg[1]) #?

circuit.measure(qreg,creg)
job = execute(circuit,Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'),shots=1024)
counts = job.result().get_counts(circuit)
print(counts)

# CNOT gate: performs a NOT on the target whenever the control is in state 1.
```

**OUTPUT:** {'01': 1024}
**MY EXPECTATION:** {'10': 1024}

Comment: Little vs. big endian issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Qiskit uses [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) ordering for both classical bits and qubits.

See [this answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/8370/9474) for more details.

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. I guess you are saying that there is no logical difference between the OUTPUT and MY EXPECTED OUTPUT ?

Comment: It is just a convention. When the first bit equals $1$ and the second bit equals $0$, and we are using little-endian ordering, we write the bitstring as $01$. That is, we write the first bit on the right-most side. On the other hand, many quantum computing books use big-endian ordering. So, they write the same bitstring as $10$

Comment: I got it, thank you.